# Expectation of Random Variable - Probability Worded Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

The part I am confused with is (c)

I found part (a) which is:

p(0) = 7/24, p(1) = 21/24, p(2) = 7/40 and p(3) = 1/120

How do we find the values for a and b, for part (c) ?

Answer (score 2):

If Debra selects $N$ red cubes, then she must have selected $(3 - N)$ black cubes, so her winnings are given by:
$$
W = 2N - 1(3 - N) = 3N - 3
$$
so $a = 3$ and $b = -3$.

Comment: oh, of-course! so simple! thank you!!